# GUI glitch while running autoware

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with Autoware 1.12.0 (source build) on Ubuntu 18.04 (Melodic).
The GUI glitch I am facing is that the window doesn't clean when UI elements redraw, so I end up with text writing over text every time I switch from one tab to the next in the runtime manager.
The terminal output is:
GtK-WARNING **: Negative content height while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtKentry)

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328788/gui-glitch-while-running-autoware/) by [ArdashirB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44073/ardashirb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known problem:

https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/utilities/issues/2

It is being actively investigated.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-07-22**:
Fixed by https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/utilities/merge_requests/25/diffs